# Wire Concealers on Exterior Wall?

Tags: electrical

I've been mounting some TVs in my new house and I've used a couple of these in-wall wire concealers (like this: https://www.sanus.com/en_US/products/cable-management/sa-iwp1/).

I haven't had any problems on the interior walls, but I've been working on a mount on a wall that is shared with the outside and has a bunch of insulation. I have a few questions -

Is it OK to install this type of kit here?

If so, how to I handle the insulation? Do I just compress it behind the wiring kit (it's pretty big) or do I need to cut out around where the box will be?

If I cut it out, do I cut it all or is it OK for there to still be some insulation remaining behind the box?

[image: Power Kit] [image: Wall Insulation]

Comment: I vote for smooshing as it won't hurt anything and if you remove it one day you won't have to find more insulation.

Comment: Well, now you've cut a nice big hole in your vapor barrier...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compressed insulation is inefficient, but it still works better than nothing at all. The maximum feasible amount is how much insulation you want, where "infeasible" is defined by bulging walls or the box springing out of the wall in cartoon-like fashion.

Comment: Also, for a small area like this, a bit of thinner insulation isn't gonna *kill* your thermal efficiency.

Comment: It's still going to be insulated way better than the finest window made, for instance.